# Datable Error: Could not find the function

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm developing a data entry screen where used can enter data and create dataTable. I also need  to create a column in the datatable based on the  user input. For this I'm using transform function in data table.

while doing so I get an error saying "Could not find function".

I'm also attaching my code for debugging

```
mkifields<-c("Financial_Year","Quarter","Month", "DB_Date","Actual_Date")
ui<- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Monthly Key Indicators"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=3,
                 textInput("Financial_Year","Financial Year"),
                 selectInput("Quarter","Quarter",c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")),
                 dateInput("Month","Month of Account", format="MM, yyyy"),
                 dateInput("DB_Date", "Detailed Booking Closing Date", format="dd-mm-yyyy"),
                 dateInput("Actual_Date","Actual date of uploading MKI",format="dd-mm-yyyy"),
                 actionButton("save6","Add",icon=icon("plus-square")),
                 actionButton("reset6","Delete",icon=icon("minus-square"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput("mkiresponses", width = 600), tags$hr()
      ))))
server<- function(input,output,session){
  mkisaveData <- function(data) {
    mkidata <- data.frame(
      Financial_Year=data["Financial_Year"],
      Quarter=data["Quarter"],
      Month=as.Date(as.numeric(data[["Month"]]),"1970-01-01"),
      Detailed_Book_Date=as.Date(as.numeric(data[["DB_Date"]]),"1970-01-01"),
      Actual_Upload_Date=as.Date(as.numeric(data[["Actual_Date"]]),"1970-01-01")
    )
    if (exists("mkiresponses")) {
      mkiresponses <<- rbind(mkiresponses, mkidata)
    } else {
      mkiresponses <<- mkidata
    }
  }
  mkiformData <- reactive({
    mkidata <- sapply(mkifields, function(x) input[[x]])
    mkidata
    #print(data)
  })
  observeEvent(input$save6, {
    mkisaveData(mkiformData())
  })
  mkiloadData <- function() {
    if (exists("mkiresponses")) {
      mkiresponses
    }
  }
  output$mkiresponses <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$save6
    input$reset6
    mki<-transform(mkiloadData(), Delay=as.numeric((mkiloadData()$Actual_Date)-(mkiloadData()$DB_Date)))
    datatable(mki,rownames=FALSE,options = list(ordering=FALSE, searching=FALSE,paging=FALSE,pageLength=FALSE,info=FALSE))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Pls help me out with solving the error

Comment: check if you have all required libraries loaded. Also check for spelling errors,..

Comment: you are calling `mkiloadData()` from `output$mkiresponses` and `mkiloadData` is not returning anything since `mkiresponses` doesn't exist (at least initially)

Answer (score 0):

Save the function `mkiloadData()` in a file and use the function source().

```
server<- function(input,output,session){

  source("/path/to/function_file.R")

  mkisaveData <- function(data) {
    mkidata <- data.frame(
      Financial_Year=data["Financial_Year"],
      Quarter=data["Quarter"],
      Month=as.Date(as.numeric(data[["Month"]]),"1970-01-01"),
      Detailed_Book_Date=as.Date(as.numeric(data[["DB_Date"]]),"1970-01-01"),
      Actual_Upload_Date=as.Date(as.numeric(data[["Actual_Date"]]),"1970-01-01")
    )
    if (exists("mkiresponses")) {
      mkiresponses <<- rbind(mkiresponses, mkidata)
    } else {
      mkiresponses <<- mkidata
    }
  }
  mkiformData <- reactive({
    mkidata <- sapply(mkifields, function(x) input[[x]])
    mkidata
    #print(data)
  })
  observeEvent(input$save6, {
    mkisaveData(mkiformData())
  })

  output$mkiresponses <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$save6
    input$reset6
    mki<-transform(mkiloadData(), Delay=as.numeric((mkiloadData()$Actual_Date)-(mkiloadData()$DB_Date)))
    DT::datatable(mki,rownames=FALSE,options = list(ordering=FALSE, searching=FALSE,paging=FALSE,pageLength=FALSE,info=FALSE))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```